# NextJS 11, api routes 404 on production

Tags: next.js, dockerfile, github-actions

I've setup an api route to create a dynamic `robots.txt` file found in `src/pages/api/robots`

```
export default function handler(req, res) {
  const host = req?.headers?.host;
  const ROOT_URL = `https://${host}`;

  res.send(`User-agent: *
Disallow: /lightbox/*
Disallow: /wapi/*
Disallow: /admin/*
Disallow: /data/
Disallow: /json

Sitemap: ${ROOT_URL}/sitemap-master.xml

Sitemap: ${ROOT_URL}/sitemaps/sitemap.xml

Sitemap: ${ROOT_URL}/sitemaps/sitemap-news.xml`);
}
```

Then in my `next.config.js` I have added a rewrite so that `/robots.txt` sources from `/api/robots`

```
const withModernizr = require('next-plugin-modernizr');
const withFonts = require('next-fonts');
const path = require('path');
const appConfig = require('./app.config.json');

module.exports = withFonts(
  withModernizr({
    trailingSlash: true,
    reactStrictMode: true,
    eslint: {
      ignoreDuringBuilds: true,
    },
    // In deployment builds, assetPrefix is used to move static directory
    assetPrefix: appConfig.imagePath ? `/_static/${appConfig.imagePath}` : undefined,
    typescript: {
      ignoreBuildErrors: true,
    },
    sassOptions: {
      includePaths: [path.join(__dirname, 'src/styles')],
    },
    experimental: {
      scrollRestoration: true,
    },
    async rewrites() {
      return [
        {
          source: '/robots.txt',
          destination: '/api/robots',
        },
      ];
    },
    webpack(config) {
      const originalEntry = config.entry;

      config.entry = async () => {
        const entries = await originalEntry();

        if (entries['main.js']) {
          entries['main.js'].unshift('intersection-observer');
        }

        return entries;
      };

      config.module.rules.push({
        test: /\.svg$/,
        use: ['@svgr/webpack'],
      });
      config.module.rules.push({
        test: /\.pdf$/i,
        type: 'asset/source',
      });
      return config;
    },
  }),
);
```

This all works locally as expected, but when in production I get a 404 going to `/robots.txt` and going to `/api/robots` directly returns the following error

```
{
  "data": null,
  "error": {
    "status": 404,
    "name": "NotFoundError",
    "message": "Not Found",
    "details": {}
  }
}
```

Perhaps it was something to do with how I deploy. I deploy via GitHub actions where I run docker build and deploy to Google Cloud Storage by pushing that docker image.

This is the `Dockerfile`

```
FROM node:16.14.2-alpine AS deps
RUN apk add --no-cache libc6-compat
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json ./
COPY .next ./.next
COPY .npmrc ./.npmrc
COPY yarn.lock ./yarn.lock
COPY app.config.json ./app.config.json
COPY src ./src
COPY public ./public
COPY cluster.js ./cluster.js
RUN yarn --frozen-lockfile --network-timeout 100000

FROM node:16.14.2-alpine AS builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=deps /app/src ./src
COPY --from=deps /app/public ./public
COPY --from=deps /app/.next ./.next
COPY --from=deps /app/cluster.js ./cluster.js
COPY --from=deps /app/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY --from=deps /app/app.config.json ./app.config.json

FROM node:16.14.2-alpine AS runner
WORKDIR /app

ENV NODE_ENV production

RUN addgroup -g 1001 -S nodejs
RUN adduser -S nextjs -u 1001

COPY --from=builder /app/src ./src
COPY --from=builder /app/public ./public
COPY --from=builder /app/.next ./.next
COPY --from=builder /app/cluster.js ./cluster.js
COPY --from=builder /app/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY --from=builder /app/app.config.json ./app.config.json

COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/.next ./.next

USER nextjs

EXPOSE 3000

ENV NEXT_TELEMETRY_DISABLED 1

WORKDIR /app
CMD ["node", "cluster.js"]
```

Here is the Github Action workflow

```
name: staging-build

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - develop

env:
  CLOUD_RUN_PROJECT_ID: ${{ secrets.STAGING_CLOUD_RUN_PROJECT_NAME }}
  CLOUD_RUN_REGION: ${{ secrets.CLOUD_RUN_REGION }}
  REPO_NAME: ${{ secrets.REPO_NAME }}

jobs:
  build-and-deploy:
    name: Setup, Build, and Deploy
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [16.14.2]

    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          lfs: true
      - name: Use Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}
        uses: actions/setup-node@v2
        with:
          node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
          cache: 'yarn'
      - name: Build static assets
        run: |-
          BUILD=${{ github.sha }}
          yarn
          node scripts/config.js \
            --apiUrl="${{ secrets.DEV_API_URL }}" \
            --env="Staging" \
            --imagePath="${{ github.sha }}"
          echo "${{ github.sha }}" > commitsha.txt
          yarn build
          mkdir ${{ github.sha }}
          mkdir ${{ github.sha }}/_next
          cp -R ./.next/static ${{ github.sha }}/_next
      # Upload static assets to cloud bucket
      - uses: google-github-actions/upload-cloud-storage@v0
        with:
          path: ${{ github.sha }}
          credentials: ${{ secrets.STAGING_GCS_SA_KEY }}
          destination: ${{ secrets.STAGING_GCS_BUCKET }}
          glob: '**/!(*.map)'
      # This step is where our service account will be authenticated
      - uses: google-github-actions/setup-gcloud@v0.2.0
        with:
          project_id: ${{ secrets.STAGING_CLOUD_RUN_PROJECT_NAME }}
          service_account_key: ${{ secrets.STAGING_GCS_SA_KEY }}
          service_account_email: ${{ secrets.STAGING_GCS_SA_EMAIL }}
      - name: Enable docker auth
        run: |-
          gcloud --quiet auth configure-docker
      - name: Build and tag image
        run: |-
          docker build . --tag "gcr.io/$CLOUD_RUN_PROJECT_ID/$REPO_NAME:$GITHUB_SHA" --build-arg build=${{ github.sha }}
      - name: Push image to GCR
        run: |-
          docker push gcr.io/$CLOUD_RUN_PROJECT_ID/$REPO_NAME:$GITHUB_SHA
      - name: Deploy
        run: |-
          gcloud run deploy $REPO_NAME --image gcr.io/$CLOUD_RUN_PROJECT_ID/$REPO_NAME:$GITHUB_SHA \
            --project $CLOUD_RUN_PROJECT_ID \
            --platform managed \
            --region $CLOUD_RUN_REGION \
            --allow-unauthenticated \
            --quiet
```

Is there something I am missing here to get API routes to work?

Comment: Dont see `next.config.js` in your `Dockerfile`. Why is that?

Comment: @RobinThomas Thanks, that was actually the issue! You can add that as the answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your `Dockerfile`, I don't see your `next.config.js` copied to the Docker image. Without that, your routes shall not work.

So do a `COPY` like:

```
COPY next.config.js ./
```

And it should work now!